# Hadoop Java Class cannot be found

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:WordCount-> so many answers relate to this issue and it seems like I am definitely missing a small point again which took me hours to figure.
I will try to be as clear as possible about the paths, code itself and other possible solutions I tried and did not work.
I am kinda sure about my correctly configuring Hadoop as everything was working up until the last stage.
But still posting the details:

1. Environment variables and paths

>

```
HADOOP VARIABLES START
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/tools.jar
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
#export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
#export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

#HADOOP VARIABLES END
```

The Class itself:

```
package com.cloud.hw03;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {

  public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
      }
    }
  }

  public static class IntSumReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "wordcount");
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

what I did for compiling and running:

1. Created jar file in the same folder with my WordCount maven project (eclipse-workspace)

   $ hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WordCount.java

   $ jar cf WordCount.jar WordCount*.class
2. Running the program: (i already created a directory and copied input-output files in hdfs)

hadoop jar WordCount.jar WordCount /input/inputfile01 /input/outputfile01

result is: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WordCount

Since I am in the same directory with WordCount.class and i created my jar file in that same directory, i am not specifying full path to WordCount, so i am running the above 2nd command in this directory :
[image]

I already added job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class); to the code so no help. I would appreciate your spending time on answering!
I am sure I am doing something unexpected again and cannot figure it out for 4 hrs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wordcount example code on the Hadoop site does not use a package

Since you do have one, you would run the fully qualified class. The exact same way as a regular Java application

```
hadoop jar WordCount.jar com.cloud.hw03.WordCount
```

Also, if you actually had a Maven project, then `hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main` is not correct. You would actually use Maven to compile and create the JAR with all the classes, not only `WordCount*` files

For example, from the folder with the pom.xml

```
mvn package
```

Otherwise, you need to be in the parent directory

```
hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main ./com/cloud/hw03/WordCount.java
```

And run the `jar cf` command also from that directory

Comment: i am in the directory com.cloud.hw03 (in the screenshot), do i still need to specify the package? Without specifying the full path, it is not able to find the WordCount class again (i ran the command you mentioned and same error- ClassNotFoundException)

Comment: The JAR contains the fully qualified class name. It has nothing to do with the folder you're running the command from

Comment: You should never manually add JARs to a Maven project ... Actually use Maven to manage your dependencies, as it was designed to do. Also, your project should work in any IDE and the terminal, not rely on "Eclipse" or "JARs on your machine" https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client/2.8.3

Comment: I thought I could change it later by creating a "real" maven project.. but in fact, as you could see from screenshot that I was able to create the jar file... I just cannot run the program itself. That's the question. And do you think it is due to that reason ? Would u advice removing all the jars from maven or create a new one from zero?

Comment: You just need to undo whatever you did in the Eclipse classpath settings, then use `<dependency>` elements instead. But besides that, you can run `jar -tf WordCount.jar`... If you do not see `com/cloud/hw03/WordCount.class` within that output, then your class isn't there, which mean that you will get "Class not found" when you attempt to run the JAR file with that classname. Feel free to search for alternatives, though. https://janzhou.org/2014/how-to-compile-hadoop.html

Comment: I created a real maven file and added all the needed dependencies. Created a jar file and running jar -tf WordCount.jar command actually shows that WordCount.class is within the jar file (without the package name). Surprisingly, I still cannot run the program as it again says that Class is not Found. I should not be using alternative approaches like compiling with javac. What I used For Compiling:                           
1. hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main *.java
2. jar cf WordCount.jar *.class    and for running: hadoop jar WordCount.jar WordCount /input /output

Comment: I needed to create the jar file by specifying package name as you mentioned, but my current directory where I should issue the command should be right before the package, i.e if package name is com.hadoop, then i needed to create a jar in the parent directory (you also mentioned id) so i marked your answer as correct. Thanks a lot!