# Simple Program in Hadoop got ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

Recently I rewrote the code in WordCount example of hadoop, but when i run it on my virtual machine (ubuntu server 14.04 with both hadoop and java set), i got **ClassNotFoundException**... I have already tired many solutions found on the Internet but they didn't work. Anything i can do to fix this?
[image: Error]

and my code is :

```
        package org.apache.hadoop.examples;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.util.StringTokenizer;
        import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
        import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
        import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
        import org.apache.hadoop.io.FloatWritable;
        import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
        import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
        import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
        import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

        import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;

        import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

        import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

        public class myhadoop 
        {

            public static int total_number = 0;

            public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> 
            {
                private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);

                private Text word = new Text();



                public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
                {
                    StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
                    while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) 
                    {

                        word.set(itr.nextToken());

                        context.write(word, one);

                        total_number = total_number + 1;

                    }

                }
            }

            public static class IntSumCombiner extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {

                private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

                public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
                {

                    int sum = 0;

                    for (IntWritable val : values) {

                    sum += val.get();

                    }

                    result.set(sum);

                    context.write(key, result);

                }

            }

            public static class ResultCountReducer extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,FloatWritable> {

                private FloatWritable result = new FloatWritable();

                public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
                {

                    int sum = 0;

                    for (IntWritable val : values) {

                    sum += val.get();

                    }
                            float frequncy = sum / total_number;

                    result.set(frequncy);

                    context.write(key, result);

                }

        }



            public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
            {

                Configuration conf = new Configuration();

                String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();

                if (otherArgs.length != 2) 
                {

                    System.err.println("Usage: myhadoop <in> <out>");

                    System.exit(2);

                }

                Job job = new Job(conf, "myhadoop");

                job.setJarByClass(myhadoop.class);

                job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);

                job.setCombinerClass(IntSumCombiner.class);

                job.setReducerClass(ResultCountReducer.class);

                job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);

                job.setOutputValueClass(FloatWritable.class);

                FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));

                FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));

                System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you put error in comment .. for me image is not visible

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.examples.myhadoop
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

Comment: Of course. @Roshan

Comment: Did it used to work? What did you change? How do you build the jar file?

Comment: @cricket_007 it was the code from WordCount (one of examples of hadoop), i change all 'WordCount' to 'myhadoop' and add something (but i think it is not the cause of this problem because the complier didn't report any error) . My build jar use command : javac myhadoop.java jar -cvf myhadoop.jar myhadoop*.class

Comment: You need to make a directory for each package of `org\apache\hadoop\examples\myhadoop.java`. Then compile the classes from the folder containing the `org` folder, as I mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50381353/2308683

Comment: i don't quite understand :(  should i creat a directory to place my jar or use another jar command (like ?)

Comment: Is  `myhadoop.class`  file created after `javac myhadoop.java`

Comment: run this command `usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar myhadoop.jar myhadoop /input /output` as the className is already specified.

Comment: I tried the command above but still error... and i find it the simplest way to solve it is to avoid it by deleting the first line of my code which declare a package name. Then instead of using Job.setJarByClass(), i should call Job.setJar(). Finally it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution From Comment:
deleting the first line i.e package import

```
'package org.apache.hadoop.examples;'
```

Change in code, replace

```
Job.setJarByClass(),
```

by

```
Job.setJar()
```